# An invalid parameter was passed to the function sql filestream issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Error occurring in my win32 application at

```
SqlFileStream writeVideo = new SqlFileStream(dbFilePath, txnContext, FileAccess.Write);
```

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my machine (Windows 7) which is used by the Win32 desktop application. I also installed SQL Server 2014 Developer edition on my machine, running web application database.

My win32 application communicaties with web application via a web service. Both SQL Server instances have SQL Filestream feature enabled.

When I stop my SQL Server 2014 instance, videos save successfully, else when both instances are running, I get the error mentioned above on trying to save the video.

Is there any conflict running the two SQL Server instances simultaneously?

Comment: The port number should be different for the two instances of SQL Server.  I think changing port number so one used port 80 and the other used port 8080 for web port should work.

Comment: not resolved through port change.

Comment: Add a check to see if txnContext is null.   I don't think dbFilePath would change nor would FileAccess.Write change.  The server would not know if the actual data inside txnContext is valid or not valid so I don't think the contents is creating the error.